# RethinkDB contains in Java

Tags: rethinkdb

How do I write this query using the RethinkDB Java API?

```
r.db('dataq').table('api').filter(
    r.and(r.row('tags_').contains('Server', 'backend')))
```

This is what I tried:

```
List<String> tags = ...; // 'Server', 'backend'
r.db('dataq').table('api').filter(row -> 
                     r.and(row.g('tags_').contains(tags))).run(conn);
```

It works for a single element.

```
r.db('dataq').table('api').filter(row -> 
                     r.and(row.g('tags_').contains(tags.get(0)))).run(conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`r.args`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/java/args/) can wrap multiple expressions in a single term:

> `r.args` is a special term that’s used to splice an array of arguments into another term. This is useful when you want to call a variadic term such as getAll with a set of arguments produced at runtime.

Having that, you can easily fix your query:

```java
RethinkDB.r.db("dataq")
    .table("api")
    .filter(doc -> doc.getField("tags_").contains(RethinkDB.r.args(tags)))
    .run(conn)
```